# Passing a dynamic parameter through URL in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two reports, the first one passes two parameters through the second report which works fine when using 'Go to Report'

However I need to use 'Go to URL' as I need to be able to control the Zoom.

The problem is, I also need to pass the 2 parameters through the URL.

These Parameters are @Reason1 and @Reason2.

I have tried using the following:

```
http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspxnameofmyreportpart&rs:Command=Render&Reason1=@Reason1&Reason2=@Reason2
```

But then it hard codes @Reason1 and @Reason2 as the values of my Reason1/Reason2 parameter value box's which obviously yields no results.

How do I structure the URL to receive the 2 parameters from the selection made in the previous report.

Comment: You should be using the in built action for drilling down to another report as this gives you more flexibility. Have you tried this? If so what goes wrong or if not what is stopping you? Also what do you mean by control the zoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not calling the sub report as an action and adding the parameters?  It seems like you are trying to make the URL do an action that is already built into the code.  Is there a specific reason?

If you had to I would use the expression but I may build the url first and verify you could copy and paste it and it would work.  Call the WebService:

```
="http:// (ServerName)/ReportServer/(pathtoreport)&(ParameterName)=" + Parameters!(ParameterName).Value + "&(ParameterName2)=" + Parameters!(ParameterName).Value
```

Comment: Have done what you suggested but am getting this error now:

The path of the item '/myprojectname/myreportname, name' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help

Comment: Other parameters work (the shorter named ones) but the URL for the one that is not working is 248 characters long, so im confused.

Comment: Can you shorten the path for deployment for testing only and see if the parameters work then?  I would try this debug method to determine if the error is resultant on the params.  Also try to go to your WebService in a browser directly and traverse from there: "http:// (Servername)/ReportServer.  It may want the report in the format list that way as you traverse as their may be issues with the interpretation of the path if it is literal would be my guess.  When you contact the Webservice directly this should be traversing giving you the path you want to use in code.

Comment: You've probably got a restricted character in one of the parameter values. This will need to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://Servername/ReportServer?/Foldername/Reportname&rs:Commnd=Render&parameter1=" & Fields!A.Value & "&parameter2=" & Fields!B.Value & "'))"
```

Use the above URL to open the report in a new window with dynamic parameters.